# How can I get all symbolic names from a Git commit hash?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-hash

If a Git commit hash has multiple tags associated with it and/or is the head of multiple branches, is there a good way to list *all* of them?

I've looked through the options to `git name-rev`, `git describe`, and `git symbolic-ref` but haven't found any options that seem to do what I want.  Frustratingly, `git name-rev` has a `--tags` option to list *only* tags but no apparent mechanism to list only branches (and `git name-rev` always seems to prefer tags over branches for me anyway).

```sh
$ git checkout -b branch1
$ git checkout -b branch2
$ git tag tag1
$ git tag tag2
$ git name-rev HEAD
HEAD tags/tag1
$ git describe --all HEAD
HEAD tags/tag1
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/branch2
```

To map a commit hash to all of its symbolic names, will I need to run `git tag --list` and `git branch --all --list` and then run `git rev-parse` on all of the results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be possible to achieve what you want thanks to the [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) command:

```
git for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD
```

Complete example session:

```
$ git init
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m a
[master (root-commit) eb3222d] a
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
$ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
$ git checkout -b branch2
Switched to a new branch 'branch2'
$ git tag tag1
$ git tag tag2
$ git tag -a tag3 -m "annotated tag"
$ git for-each-ref --points-at=HEAD
eb3222db1821633a54ccd0a6434e883c4cb71b98 commit refs/heads/branch1
eb3222db1821633a54ccd0a6434e883c4cb71b98 commit refs/heads/branch2
eb3222db1821633a54ccd0a6434e883c4cb71b98 commit refs/heads/master
eb3222db1821633a54ccd0a6434e883c4cb71b98 commit refs/tags/tag1
eb3222db1821633a54ccd0a6434e883c4cb71b98 commit refs/tags/tag2
0dbba96f519c2ad1b470f97171230004addff896 tag    refs/tags/tag3
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that normally `git log` shows me all of the names that I'm looking for.  Looking at `git log`'s formatting options, I alternatively could use:

```
$ git log --format='%d -1 HEAD
 (HEAD -> branch2, tag: tag2, tag: tag1, branch1)
```

The formatting of the output from [ErikMD's `git for-each-ref` suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504960/) probably is easier to deal with though, so that's likely what I'll end up using.